# Using APPCMD to clear the set of custom error definitions

Tags: iis-7

I would like to remove all the custom error definitions within the `<httpErrors>` section of the IIS configuration.  The XML schema allows a `<clear/>` under `<httpErrors>` but I cannot seem to see how to clear the set out using the `APPCMD` tool.

Is such an action possible? Is there a better way than using `APPCMD` to do this?  It needs to be done programmatically--not interactively.

Comment: You can try to use `ConfigurationSectionCollection.Remove(String) Method` to remove `<httpErrors>`,  and refer to this link to GetSection: [config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpErrors")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/#c).